# Compiled requirejs modules require calls are executing before modules are defined resulting in 'Undefined is not a function'

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've compiled my requirejs file using r.js and occasionally on page load, modules aren't defined as (I'm assuming) that require and define calls are running asynchronously and modules aren't getting defined by the time the require call has executed.

I'm pretty sure my shim is correct, my waitSeconds is set to 0 (infinite) and all my exports are set up.

Here's my (shortened) requirejs file:

```
requirejs.config({    
    defaultPath: 'javascript',
    waitSeconds: 0,
    // paths to plugins
    paths   :   {
        'jquery'              :   'plugins/jquery-1.9.1.min',
        'owl'                 :   'plugins/owl.carousel.min'
    },
    // dependency order if applicable
    shim    :   {
        'jquery'              :   {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'owl'                 :   {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'owlCarousel'
        }
    }  
});

require(['jquery','owl'], function($, owlCarousel){
    $('.carousel').owlCarousel();
});
```

Comment: You don't need a `shim` for jquery as it [supports AMD out of the box](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#modulename). This *could* lead to intermittent timing problems as described.

Comment: I've removed the shim for jquery but the same thing's happening